# Internet doesn't work into android virtual device

Tags: android, proxy

I have read quite many posts about this topic but nothing was relevant for my "special" case. Hope someone can help :)

My scenario is the following:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (clear installation)
- Android SDK 21.0.1 & Android SDK 22.0.1
- AVD's created: Android 2.2 & Android 2.3.3. Settings: CPU=ARM; RAM=512; Internal Storage= 500MB; SDcard= 2000 MB; all the rest by default.
- Internet working under proxy
- Input proxy settings into Tools -> Options (no user/ no password)
- Initialized emulator -> Wireless & Networks -> Create NewAPN -> APN=www -> Proxy= xx.xx.xx.xx -> Port= xx -> username=not set -> password = not set -> all others options = by default
- When trying to access internet through AVD browser I got the error = "The requested URL could bot be retrieved. Access denied"
- But when I try to access internet out of AVD (normal Ubuntu's browser) = no problems at all...

does someone have any idea about how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It's not a DNS problem. I checked with Google's IP (173.194.32.32) and still didn't work

Comment: 3G symbol is visble on AVD ????

Comment: nothing?? noone can help?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?